# cannot find -lMylib

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two ROS packages. Package A loads the library Mylib, which is a .so file.
package B uses package A with find packages().

Package A compiles without any issues, while package B fails for the reason: cannot find -lMylib.

I don't understand why Mylib is required by package B if Package A loaded it without problems

---**EDIT**----

These are the Cmake Formats
packageA

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(PackageA)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID "--with-cc=/usr/bin/mpicc --with-cxx=/usr/bin/mpicxx -lmpi_cxx")
add_compile_options(-std=c++14)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    moveit_core
    moveit_ros_planning
    moveit_ros_planning_interface
    moveit_msgs
    
    )
catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    message_runtime
    roscpp moveit_msgs moveit_ros_planning
    moveit_ros_planning_interface
    moveit_core
    DEPENDS
    EIGEN3

)
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    lib
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
link_directories(lib/myLibFolder/)
set(MY_LIB_NAME MyLib)

add_library(some_lib src/some_lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(some_lib ${MY_LIB_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_library(some_lib_2 src/some_lib_2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(some_lib_2 some_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_library(packageA_launcher src/PackageA_launcher.cpp)
target_link_libraries( packageA_launcher some_lib_2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

packageB

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3) 
project(PackageB) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 ") 
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    cmake_modules
    PackageA       ) 
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system) catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
    include
    LIBRARIES
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    DEPENDS
    PackageA)
add_executable(some_PackageB_cpp
    src/some_PackageB_cpp.cpp        )
target_link_libraries(some_PackageB_cpp packageA_launcher  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ) }
```

The error comes from package B.Package A compiles.

@mgruhler
How can I say

> "hey package B, just link against
> everything that package A links
> against"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341803/cannot-find--lmylib/) by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-01-16**:
just to clarify, `MyLib` is some third-party (or whatever) compiled library file (`.so`, so a shared library), that you put into `PackageA/lib/myLibFolder`, right?

It is not located somewhere outside of `PackageA`?

**Comment by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on 2020-01-16**:
@mgruhler Exactly, it's a .so file located inside PackageA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I don't understand why Mylib is required by package B if Package A loaded it without problems

Well, package A doesn't load the shared library `Mylib`. You specify that whatever you compile in package A should dynamically link to `Mylib.so`. It is not included in package A in any way.

Now, if you use whatever you compile in package A in package B, you need to tell package B that it needs to link against whatever package A needs to link to as well. You don't have to explicitly do this, you can actually do this as in "hey package B, just link against everything that package A links against", by specifying this correctly in the `CMakeLists.txt` of package A.

This should explain why it is not working. If you want to know how to make it work, please post a new question and don't forget to include a copy of your `CMakeLists.txt`, ideally of both packages (and please remove any comments).

---

**Update**

> How can I say
>
> > "hey package B, just link against everything that package A links against"?

You've already done that, via `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... PackageA)` and `target_link_libraries(some_PackageB_cpp ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`.
You don't have to specify `package_A_launcher` there explicitely.

Minor note on the `CMakeLists.txt` of PackageB: you should have `PackageA` specified as a `CATKIN_DEPENDS`, not as a `DEPEND` in the `catkin_package` macro. Other than that, this one seems fine. (Though I wonder why you use `mpicc` in packageA, but not in B. Maybe this also has some influence?)

You need to properly specify PackageA, though. I.e. you have to export to catkin/cmake, which libraries you provide from your PackageA. Otherwise, package B cannot find them.

You do this also in the `catkin_package` call by adding the `LIBRARIES` and `INCLUDE_DIRS` sections. See the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html#exporting).

As you provide `myLib` as a compiled `.so`, you'll have to work around a few things, though.
I'd recommend investigating if there is another way, e.g.

1. Check, if you can get it from `apt` (you'll probably have done that, though)
2. If it is a cmake project, follow the advice from #q246012
3. If it is something else, you're probably best of by providing a wrapper package for this. Take [cob_extern/libntcan](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_extern/tree/indigo_dev/libntcan) as an example on what needs to be done...
4. you can also do the above within your package, but I'd recommend keeping those two (PackageA and MyLib) separate...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on 2020-01-16**:
Thanks! I Edited the question